# Contrained coefficient in lm regression in R

Tags: r, regression

I have a question about regression in R. I want to realise some OLS with this equations. But I don't know how to constraint to one the coefficients associate with the y and y(t-1) in the first equation. I would like to use lm equation but I don't know if is possible with this constraint.
Thank's for your attention and your asnwers! Have a nice day!

[image]

Comment: You could estimate a Gaussian glm with an offset equal to $\tilde{y}_{t} - \tilde{y}_{t-1}$.  Would that work?

Comment: `lm(diff(y)~diff(ytilde))`

Comment: These equations are not clear; the terms are not explained. What do the equations mean and what is the constraint?